# How do you calculate proficiency bonus for monsters?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, proficiency, monster-design

I'm making monsters on Dnd beyond, and I always get the proficiency bonus wrong. I need to know how to calculate proficiency bonus for a challenge rating 8 monster.

Comment: In this case I believe dnd-beyond is an ill fitting tag and it should be dnd-5e instead as dndbeyond is a tag used to refer to questions about the site itself as opposed to 5e.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @MaikoChikyu I've added the 5e tag since DDB is a 5e exclusive platform.

Answer (score 13):

#### Use the "Proficiency Bonus by Challenge Rating" table from the *Monster Manual*.

Page 8 of the *Monster Manual* has a table which tells the proficiency bonus for a monster with a given Challenge Rating. It is also available [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#ProficiencyBonusbyChallengeRating) in the *Basic Rules*. A CR 8 monster has a proficiency bonus of +3.

#### The monster homebrew tool does this for you based on the CR you enter.

In the DND Beyond homebrew monster tool, this will be automatically calculated for you. The edit page where you can adjust the Challenge Rating for your monster does not have any place to override the proficiency bonus, and will be calculated for you and displayed in the stat block based on the table mentioned above.

Comment: For my curiosity, is the formula the same as for PCs using CR instead of level? (aka an increase at 5,9,13...) This lines up for lvl8.

Comment: @3C273 Yes, CRs 1-20 are the same prof as levels 1-20 for PCs, and the same pattern continues up to CR 30, with prof going up when CR = 1 mod 4.

Comment: Fixed formula: `=MAX(FLOOR((creature_level_or_cr - 1) / 4), 0) + 2`

Comment: See: [Calculate PB from CR/level](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/161150/what-is-the-mathematical-formula-for-proficiency-bonus-vs-level-cr)

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin.. It has the exception.. That's what the MAX() is for. It works on 0 CR creatures and fractional CR creatures. If the CR is less than 1, then subtracting 1 would normally be less than 0. But this will just start them at 0, so the `+2` gives the correct value.

Comment: @MivaScott I missed that, nice.

Comment: Heh. Didn't realize my calc was off for 0 :-) Guess it's never come up...