# Does the Resilient feat give you proficiency in the skills associated with the chosen ability?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, skills, proficiency

If you take the Resilient feat, do you become proficient in the associated skills?

For example, if you were not proficient in Dex saving throws and choose Dex when you take the Resilient feat, are you now proficient in Stealth, Acrobatics, and Sleight of Hand?

Comment: Related on [Can someone explain what the proficiency bonus is?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31854/can-someone-explain-what-the-proficiency-bonus-is-in-dd-5e-next-exactly)

Answer (score 29):

## No, Resilient grants proficiency in Saving Throws only

The PHB (pp 168) says the [Resilient](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/resilient) feat gives you (my emphasis):

> ...**proficiency in saving throws** using the chosen ability.

Skills and ability checks are separate mechanics that require proficiency of their own from a source (background, race, class etc.)

### Related Skills *could* be improved, but you're still not proficient

If the ability chose to be Resilient in was an odd number originally, the feat also

> Increase[s] the chosen ability score by 1...

The increase of 1 on an odd modifier would then improve your modifier by 1 as you reach the next even value. Skills that your DM calls for utilizing that modifier would also then increase by 1.

Comment: It's not really what the questioner is asking about, but you might mention that Resilient also gives a +1 to the ability in addition to saving through proficiency. If that increases the ability modifier (because you went from an odd to an even ability score), the feat *will* improve all rolls made using the attribute (even non-proficient skill checks), if only by one.

Comment: Another good phrase to keep in mind is the difference between "saving throws" and "checks". Even a straight dexterity check does not benefit from the proficiency of the Resilient feat.

Comment: @Blckknght Great point - I've added.

Comment: @MilesBedinger I added that into my first section - thank you!